# Removing last row in csv

Tags: python, csv

I'm trying to remove the last row in a csv but I getting an error: `_csv.Error: string with NUL byte`

This is what I have so far:

```
dcsv = open('PnL.csv' , 'a+r+b')
cWriter = csv.writer(dcsv, delimiter=' ')
cReader = csv.reader(dcsv)
for row in cReader:
    cWriter.writerow(row[:-1])
```

I cant figure out why I keep getting errors

Comment: Perhaps there is a NUL byte in your file?

Comment: I don't think this would do what you want anyway. `row[:-1]` will give you the current row without the last element. It won't give you all rows except for the last one. In other words, this removes the last _column_, not the last row.

Comment: Also, which line in the script is giving you the error?

Comment: On windows+Python 2.7 at least, 'a+r+b' is an invalid mode

Comment: Remember: it is a very good practice, almost obligatory, to [accept one answer to your qustion](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#howtoask)! Apparently you did not accept any answer to any question you asked.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I would just read in the whole file with readlines(), pop out the last row, and then write that with csv module

```
import csv
f = open("summary.csv", "r+w")
lines=f.readlines()
lines=lines[:-1]

cWriter = csv.writer(f, delimiter=',')
for line in lines:
    cWriter.writerow(line)
```

Comment: This can break if there is a quoted field with a newline in the last CSV-line, so that the logical line extends over multiple lines.

Answer (score 2):

This should work

```
import csv
f = open('Pnl.csv', "r+")
lines = f.readlines()
lines.pop()
f = open('Pnl.csv', "w+")
f.writelines(lines)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure what you're doing with the 'a+r+b' file mode and reading and writing to the same file, so won't provide a complete code snippet, but here's a simple method to skip any lines that contains a NUL byte in them in a file you're reading, whether it's the last, first, or one in the middle being read.

The trick is to realize that the docs say the csvfile argument to a `csv.writer()` "can be any object which supports the *iterator* protocol and returns a string each time its `next()` method is called." This means that you can replace the file argument in the call with a simple filter iterator function defined this way:

```
def filter_nul_byte_lines(a_file):
    for line in a_file:
        if '\x00' not in line:
            yield line
```

and use it in a way similar to this:

```
dcsv = open('Pnl.csv', 'rb+')
cReader = csv.reader(filter_nul_byte_lines(dcsv))
for row in cReader:
    print row
```

This will cause any lines with a NUL byte in them to be ignored while reading the file. Also this technique works on-the-fly as each line is read, so it does not require reading the entire file into memory at once or preprocessing it ahead of time.