# delete last blank row csv file

Tags: python, csv

I have a csv file in which I want to change the written data. But when writing data, I get a blank line at the end of the file. How do I delete the last blank line?

```
import csv
accounts = []
account = []
sep = ";"
#get data to accounts
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    csvreader = csv.reader(csvfile)
    for row in csvreader:
        text = [row]
        uncuttext = sep.join(row)
        account = uncuttext.split(sep)
        accounts.append(account)

#edit data
def edit(position: str, rate: float):
    for x in range(len(accounts)):
        plat = float(ucty[x][5])
        if accounts[x][7] == position:
            plat = round(plat * rate)
            accounts[x][5] = str(plat)


#save data
def save():
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='') as csvfile:
        csvwriter = csv.writer(csvfile, delimiter=sep, quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
        csvwriter.writerows(accounts)
```

I tried [How write csv file without new line character in last line?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19309834/how-write-csv-file-without-new-line-character-in-last-line) but it didn't work.

Comment: You should make sure to distinguish between a blank last line and just a line terminator on the last line.   How are you verifying this is a problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you referring to something like this?

```
1,truck,purple
2,car,red
3,van,blue
--blank line
```

Try something like this where you remove the newline from the last record on read in.

```
with open(filename, 'r') as csvfile:
    lines = csvfile.readlines()
    last_line = lines[len(lines)-1]
    lines[len(lines)-1] = last_line.rstrip()
    for row in lines:
        ....

....

#save data
def save():
    with open(filename, 'w', newline='', escapechar='', lineterminator='') as csvfile:
        ....
```

Comment: Exactly like that. I tried to fix it with https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10954748/removing-last-row-in-csv, but without success.

Comment: @zuiopplay added more to my answer